# Spring boot set values in a list of model objects and return as JSON

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am new to spring boot. I am trying to create a JSON list and return that as a response for a get request.

This is what my controller has:

```
@GetMapping("/dataReport")
public dataModel getDataReport(@RequestParam(value = "Nbr", required = true)) {
            dataModel response = new dataModel();
            response = dataService.getDataItems();
            return response;
}
```

dataService.java
Service class

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import model.dataModel;
import model.CheckSpecs;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Service
@Slf4j
public class dataService{

    public dataModel getDataItems() {
        dataModel response = new dataModel();

            response.setAcn("851");

            CheckSpecs c1 = new CheckSpecs();
            c1.setCheck("SVC -");

            CheckSpecs c2 = new CheckSpecs();
            c2.setCheck("B - 5");

            List<CheckSpecs> checkSpecsList = new ArrayList<CheckSpecs>();
            checkSpecsList.add(c1);
            checkSpecsList.add(c2);
            response.setCheckSpecs(checkSpecsList);
            
            return response;
}
```

Main Model class
dataModel.java

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class dataModel {

    private String acn;
    private List<CheckSpecs> checkSpecs;
}
```

Model class with object of main model class
CheckSpecs.java

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class CheckSpecs {

    private String check;
}
```

Currently it's returning the value of string variable in the json response, but returning null for the list of model. Do i need to use string builder or JSONProperty?

```
{
  "acn": "851",
  "checkSpecs": null,
}
```

Expected:

```
{
  "acn": "851",
  "checkSpecs": [
    {
      "check": "xyz"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: your return type is data, not dataModel, for your endpoint. Does the data class have the getters necessary for Jackson to serialize? (Don't see that class so you could be doing something a bit odd with variable shadowing)

Comment: @AnthonyCathers the return type is dataModel, not data which has annotated getters & setters. That was a typo. Please check the updated code.

Comment: Honestly don't see anything there that would prevent it being serialized Set a breakpoint and check the object that's actually being returned, does it actually hold the values you expect?

Comment: I am not able to debug due to some other issues that can't be by passed, that's the problem.